# JavaScript - Print a Histogram from a given array

Tags: javascript, arrays

// Given an array of integers [2, 1, 2, 101, 4, 95, 3, 250, 4, 1, 2, 2, 7, 98, 123, 99, ...]

I'm trying to Write a function (with linear run-time complexity) to print the following tabular output with ‘xxx' that resembles a histogram (the output should closely match the sample output below, including "99+" to capture the count for all numbers > 99):

```
Num | count
1 | xx
2 | xxxx
3 | x
4 | xx
```

98 | x
   99 | x
   99+| xxx

Comment: What have you tried? This is just going  through each element and finding it's count then displaying that as xs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const dict = {}; // Empty dictionary
var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
const maxRange = 5; // elements above maxRange will be clubbed in the same range.

//var arr = [2, 1, 2, 101, 4, 95, 3, 250, 4, 1, 2, 2, 7, 98, 123, 99];
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 6, 7, 1, 8, 10, 11, 12];

// iterate the array and set and update the counter in map
arr.forEach(function(num) {

  min = Math.min(min, num); // find min
  if (num > maxRange) {
    num = maxRange + 1;
  }
  dict[num] = dict[num] ? dict[num] + 1 : 1;
});

console.log("Num | Count");

// Print the occurrences per item in array starting from min to max
while (min <= maxRange + 1) {
  if (!dict[min]) { // print only those numbers which are defined in dictionary
    min++;
    continue;
  }
  var xArr = []
  var range = dict[min];
  for (i = 0; i < range; i++) {
    xArr.push('x');
  }

  var disp = (min <= maxRange) ? (min + "   | " + xArr.join("")) : (maxRange + "+  | " + xArr.join(""));
  console.log(disp);
  min = min + 1;
}
```

Comment: this is close too, but it puts output for numbers that are not in the array with NO x's, so if you have [1,2,5,3,2,2,1,5,5,99] it has 4 with a blank Count and then 6...98 with blank counts.

Comment: So you do want the numbers which are not present as well?

Comment: no, just the numbers that are in the array and how many times they occur, AND if a number is greater than 99, then it output like 99+ | XXXXX

Comment: @KawikaMoss, now the program displays in sorted order as expected! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try iterating over the array using the forEach() method. then create an array of "x"'s as long as the current item in the array. Then use the join method to join the array into a string of x's.

I haven't included how to handle numbers over 99 but I think you this should be enough to get you started. The solution would involve using a conditional statement to check if the number is above 99 and printing accordingly.

i got the following output from my example:

```
Num | Count
2 ' |' 'xx'
4 ' |' 'xxxx'
6 ' |' 'xxxxxx'
8 ' |' 'xxxxxxxx'
```

have fun!

```
var arr = [2,4,6,8]

printHistogram = (array) => {
  console.log("Num", '|', "Count")
  array.forEach((x, i) => { //iterate over the array (x = current item, i = index)
    var arrToJoin =[] //create an empty array
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      arrToConcat.push('x') //add an "x" to the array
    }
    console.log(i, ' |', arrToConcat.join(''))
  })

}

printHistogram(arr)
```

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for, except the empty array of X's is actually putting the value of the number in there, so the number 2 is putting 2 X's in the array. What I'm looking for is, if 2 is in the collection 4 times, that it have 4 X's for the number 2. So if you have arr = [2,2,2,3,4,4] then the histogram would have 2 | XXXX and 4 | XX...

Comment: Ok I see. Maybe update your question to make that a little more clear. In that case you might want to try creating an array containing each unique number and then comparing each item in that back to the original array to see how many times it occurs. Maybe you could use the array.include() method to do this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=example

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

create an array of all the unique numbers called arrToCompare

then iterate over that array and compare each number to each number in the original array. If they are equal push an x to the array to join. Join it and log it with the appropriate symbols.

```
var arr = [7, 7, 8, 9, 2,4,6,8,2]

printHistogram = (array) => {
  var arrToCompare =[]
  console.log("Num", '|', "Count")
  array.forEach((x, i) => {
    arrToCompare.includes(x) ? "" : arrToCompare.push(x)
  })

  arrToCompare.forEach(function(x) {
    var arrToJoin = []
    array.forEach(function(i) {
      if(i === x) {
        arrToJoin.push('x')
      }
    })
    console.log(x, '|', arrToJoin.join(''))
  })
}

printHistogram(arr)
```